# Native android - Preset the zoom on the basis of a bounding box for a object in image

Tags: java, android, kotlin, imageview

I am working on an app that supports zoomable images

Currently, I am stuck at a point where I can not find a solution on how to programmatically scale (or zoom in) the image in an image view so that, in the resultant scaled image the object of interest is not cut off.

The app is receiving the coordinates of objects of interest relative to the original image's resolution.

From the coordinates of objects, I can calculate the bounding box for an object of interest

For Example

[image: Image with different objects]

**Image with different objects**

[image: Object of interest]

**Object of interest (Marked with blue color bounding box)**

[image: Programmatically scaled image inside image view]

**Programmatically scaled image inside image view**

I have tried this github library
https://github.com/jsibbold/zoomage

In the above-mentioned library, I tried doing some changes
This library provides double tap to zoom
I have abstracted those lines of code and put them in a function

As I am already getting a bounding box of object of interest, I have calculated the center of that
and then called the same function with center x and center y

```
public void scaleAt(float x, float y) {
        matrix.set(getImageMatrix());
        matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
        updateBounds(matrixValues);
        Matrix zoomMatrix = new Matrix(matrix);
        zoomMatrix.postScale(doubleTapToZoomScaleFactor, doubleTapToZoomScaleFactor, x, y);
        animateScaleAndTranslationToMatrix(zoomMatrix, RESET_DURATION);
}


private void updateBounds(final float[] values) {
        if (getDrawable() != null) {
            bounds.set(values[Matrix.MTRANS_X],
                    values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y],
                    getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth() * values[Matrix.MSCALE_X] + values[Matrix.MTRANS_X],
                    getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() * values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y] + values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y]);
        }
    }


private void animateScaleAndTranslationToMatrix(final Matrix targetMatrix, final int duration) {

        final float[] targetValues = new float[9];
        targetMatrix.getValues(targetValues);

        final Matrix beginMatrix = new Matrix(getImageMatrix());
        beginMatrix.getValues(matrixValues);

        //difference in current and original values
        final float xsdiff = targetValues[Matrix.MSCALE_X] - matrixValues[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
        final float ysdiff = targetValues[Matrix.MSCALE_Y] - matrixValues[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];
        final float xtdiff = targetValues[Matrix.MTRANS_X] - matrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        final float ytdiff = targetValues[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] - matrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

        resetAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1f);
        resetAnimator.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

            final Matrix activeMatrix = new Matrix(getImageMatrix());
            final float[] values = new float[9];

            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                float val = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                activeMatrix.set(beginMatrix);
                activeMatrix.getValues(values);
                values[Matrix.MTRANS_X] = values[Matrix.MTRANS_X] + xtdiff * val;
                values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] = values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] + ytdiff * val;
                values[Matrix.MSCALE_X] = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X] + xsdiff * val;
                values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y] = values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y] + ysdiff * val;
                activeMatrix.setValues(values);
                setImageMatrix(activeMatrix);
            }
        });

        resetAnimator.addListener(new SimpleAnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                setImageMatrix(targetMatrix);
            }
        });

        resetAnimator.setDuration(duration);
        resetAnimator.start();
    }
```

It produces this type of result

[image: Custom try]

Please help me solve this issue

Thank you